# Which prawnto repository for rails 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, prawnto

`git://github.com/thorny-sun/prawnto.git` and `http://cracklabs.com/prawnto` are gone.

Where is the *good* `prawnto` for rails 2.3.x now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/smecsia/prawnto looks like a good option - it appears it's still being maintained, and they're also publishing it as a gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/prawnto

I'm sure you're already aware of this, but it might be worth considering changing your PDF generation code to remove any dependency on prawnto if you have any intention on upgrading your app to rails 3.x.x as prawnto most definiately does **not** work on rails 3.